# How to center integer values in JTextFields?

Tags: java, jtextfield

```
x = new JTextField("");

count1 =22; 
String s1 = new Integer(count1).toString();
x.setText(s1);
```

How can I make the entry in the JTextfield x to be in the center. I know i can do something like

> x.setText("  " +s1+ "  ");

But I want the Jtextfield only contain "integer" value for a purpose. 
So is there a way I can do something like ?

> x.setText(s1, JTextField.Center);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x.setHorizontalAlignment(x.CENTER);

Answer (score 0):

[Swing documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29) as always comes to the rescue.